# Regular Expression String Detect

Tags: r, regex, string

Say I have a string such as "J1P3V9". I also have strings such as "0H44J4".  I want to only detect string which follow the first patter of Letter, Number, Letter, Number, Letter, Number.

What is a regex expression to match only these instances?

Comment: `grepl("\\w\\d\\w\\d\\w\\d", c("J1P3V9", "0H44J4"))`

Comment: @r2evans: This is matching `012345`

Comment: Good catch. `grepl("[[:alpha:]]\\d[[:alpha:]]\\d[[:alpha:]]\\d", c("J1P3V9", "0H44J4","123456"))`, which is now much closer to Rui's answer.

Answer (score 1):

This regex does your job,

```
\b([A-Z]\d){3}\b
```

`\b` makes sure it doesn't match partially in a bigger string.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/1Zf2rs/1)**

In case you want to include lowercase alphabets too, the regex becomes,

```
\b([a-zA-Z]\d){3}\b
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex.

```
s <- c("J1P3V9", "0H44J4")

pattern <- paste(rep("[[:alpha:]][[:digit:]]", 3), collapse = "")

grep(pattern, s, value = TRUE)
#[1] "J1P3V9"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:[A-Z]\\d){3}
```

Usage:

```
mystring <- c("J1P3V9", "0H44J4")

grepl("(?:[A-Z]\\d){3}", mystring) 
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: This is matching `012345`

Answer (score 0):

You might use

```
\b(?:[a-zA-Z]\d){3}\b
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/7ww2q5/2).

---

Or, more verbose but not supported in `R`:

```
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<letter>[a-zA-Z])
    (?<number>\d)
)
\b(?:(?&letter)(?&number)){3}\b
```

---

Jokes aside, don't rely on `\w` which is a shortcut for `[a-zA-z0-9_]` and will most likely match more than you want.